# Oracle Substring (substrb) Split on space

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have two fields 10 characters and 40 characters in length named `HOS_NAME` and `HOS_NAME1`.
Under the old requirement, I needed to fit the `HOSPITAL_NAME` in both these fields.  I put the first 10 characters in the first field(`HOS_NAME`) and the remaining in next field(`HOS_NAME1`) by using

```
substrb(HOSPITAL_NAME, 0, 10) AS HOS_NAME, substrb(HOSPITAL, 11) AS HOS_NAME1
```

However, I need to meet a new requirement: If a space is found within the first 10 characters, then the remaining characters after the space should move to the next field. So, how can I achieve this?

Example: `HOSPITAL_NAME` is `'GRACE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL'`

- Under the existing design, `HOS_NAME` is `'GRACE MEMO'` and `HOS_NAME1` is `'RIAL HOSPITAL'`.
- With the new design, `HOS_NAME` should be `'GRACE '` and `HOS_NAME1` should be `'MEMORIAL HOSPITAL'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, both `HOS_NAME` and `HOS_NAME1` are currently stored in the column `HOSPITAL_NAME`? And if the first space is not within the first 10 characters, then `HOS_NAME` will be the first 10 characters and `HOS_NAME1` the rest?

Comment: By the way, `SUBSTRB()` can return confusing results since it returns *bytes* and not *characters*. For the latter you want `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JCOLLECT.GET_SUB_STRING(STR IN VARCHAR2, STR_DELIMITOR IN VARCHAR2:='.',STR_PART IN VARCHAR2:='1') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS STR_RET VARCHAR2(4000):=NULL; BEGIN
IF STR_PART = '1' THEN        
    STR_RET := substr(STR, 1, instr(STR,STR_DELIMITOR,1,1)-1);        
ELSE    
    STR_RET := substr(STR, instr(STR,STR_DELIMITOR,1,STR_PART-1)+1,instr(STR, STR_DELIMITOR, 1,STR_PART)- instr(STR, STR_DELIMITOR, 1,STR_PART-1)-1);        
END IF; RETURN STR_RET; END;
```

Then you can use it like this:

`SELECT GET_SUB_STRING(COLUMN_NAME,',','1') FROM YOUR_TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

If your last part does never (!) contains the space-character you can get your split-position by searching the first space occurence from the right side by passing -1 to `instr`:

```
select  substr( 'GRACE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL' , 0 , instr( 'GRACE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL', ' ' , -1 ) - 1) HOS_NAME
       ,substr( 'GRACE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL' , instr( 'GRACE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL', ' ' , -1 )+1)  HOS_NAME1
 from dual;
```

Specificly:

```
select  substr( HOSPITAL_NAME , 0 , instr( HOSPITAL_NAME, ' ' , -1 ) - 1) HOS_NAME
       ,substr( HOSPITAL_NAME , instr( HOSPITAL_NAME, ' ' , -1 )+1)  HOS_NAME1
 from yourTable;
```

The additional `+1`and `-1` are just to strip of the found space character.

Maybe you should consider refactoring your data-model ( storing seperate things in seperate columns ) to ged rid of the whole affair after a one-time cleanup.